# Imagemagick composite geometry not merging photos

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have the following command which is mean't to merge a photo onto a frame and position 10px from the top left corner.

```
composite -geometry +10+10 frame.jpg photo.jpeg photo_frame.jpg
```

However, all I get in photo_frame.jpg is a duplicate of photo.jpeg. I have event swapped the 2 around and then I just get the frame.jpg. So, it's not merging them for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: I haven't used ImageMagick, but according to the documentation something like this should do the trick: `composite -compose atop -geometry +10+10 photo.jpeg frame.jpg photo_frame.jpg`

Comment: your a genius. That did the trick!

Comment: Nice! I'm posting this as an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
composite -compose atop -geometry +10+10 photo.jpeg frame.jpg photo_frame.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to include the option `-compose dst-over`.  See the following for more usage information: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php